# Pivot query in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to convert rows into columns.

- Table Format.

| PolicyNo | Month | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Aug-23 | 100 |
| 456 | sep-23 | 150 |

- Output Required

| PolicyNo | Aug-23 | sep-23 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 |  | 100 0 |
| 456 | 0 | 150 |

Comment: Use `case` statement. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE

Comment: SQL strongly and statically typed; it is not dynamic. This means that you can only pivot to predefined columns *(the result set column names can not depend on the data, only data values can depend on data)*. For example, I can write code for pivoting those exact months, but if you change the data you wouldn't get new or additional columns. That is one reason your starting structure is used in SQL *(and that what you're asking is a code-smell and likely a SQL Anti-Pattern)*.